# Do "This was a test" edit approvals show when you fail?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, voting, testing

I've seen a number of requested question edits and votes which were obviously bad, so I turned them down. I'll occasionally see, "This was only a test. You passed!"

My question is: Does StackOverflow show when you fail?

Comment: Yes, you are shown when you failed an audit; doing so too often can lead to a (temporary) review ban.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely told when you fail a review audit. The goal is to educate users on how to review properly, not to ban them.

Comment: You could just fail one intentionally and see what happens :)